# How to get repeatable form-field data?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, form-fields-types, repeatable-field

I'm using Repeatable field Type.

The data from database are:

```
{"social_icon":["fa fa-facebook","fa fa-twitter","fa fa-linkedin"],"social_link":["https://www.facebook.com/user","https://www.twitter.com/user","https://www.linkedin.com/user"]}
```

array made wit `$array_links = json_decode($social_links, true);`

```
Array ( [social_icon] => Array ( [0] => fa fa-facebook [1] => fa fa-twitter [2] => fa fa-linkedin ) [social_link] => Array ( [0] => https://www.facebook.com/user [1] => https://www.twitter.com/user [2] => https://www.linkedin.com/user ) ) 1
```

if I get information through loop:

```
<?php foreach ($array_links as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $content) {
                    echo $content.'<br>';
                }
            } ?>
```

It shows me the following

```
fa fa-facebook
fa fa-twitter
fa fa-linkedin
https://www.facebook.com/user
https://www.twitter.com/user
https://www.linkedin.com/user
```

I want to build it:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook/user"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

get data with `$array_links[0][1];`not serve me, because they use some 6 links, and other links will not use.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group each set of field by the key.

Call the parameter and convert to array:

```
$social_links = $params->get('social_links');
$array_links = json_decode($social_links, true);
```

Create a function in your **helper.php** that will group them by key

```
public function group_by_key($array) 
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $sub) 
    {
        foreach ($sub as $k => $v) 
        {
            $result[$k][] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then push `$array_links` through the function and called it in **mod_mymodule.php**

```
$filtered_array = group_by_key($array_links);
```

Then loop through the result and display however you liek:

```
foreach ($filtered_array as $key => $val) 
{   
    echo '<a href="' . $val[0] . '"><i class="' . $val[1] . '"></i></a>';
}
```

Comment: Use this code in modules. in this case are extra fields for com_content; and using this function, when there is nothing in the database, shows me error. @Lodder

Comment: @Leoalv - What error are you being show?

Comment: The error is `invalid argument supplied for foreach()` . And is detected within the function. The error occurs when a user does not fill your social links

Comment: Then write a simple if clause to test against the user input, if the social data from the input is empty, skip the processing.